# While Calling Django Api On React Error is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

Anyone Please Help me I need to submit my project this week I am getting a problem for a week.

Error is :-->

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/single/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please Help me

Comment: You need add or allow allow the site to the cors list on your server.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access the server from your react app it is called a Cross Origin request, by default a domain it is not allowed to access API hosted on another domain.

Your ReactJs app is on a port ( 3000 ) and your server on another and this cause this problem.

You have to enable CORS on your server.

You can try with :

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

More on this you can find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-cors-headers-in-your-django-project/)

Comment: I have added chrome extension as Moesif CORS and its working will that harm any things while deploying ??

Comment: That doesn't solve your problem at all. It's just a temporary fix.